Why do we need recursion to define ordinal arithmetic?
On notation: $\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\g{\gamma} \def\ZF{\textbf{ZF}} \def\Suc{\text{Suc}} \def\Lim{\text{Lim}} \def\f{\varphi} \def\x{\xi} \def\y{\psi} \def\ON{\text{ON}}$ let $\ON$ be the class of all ordinals and $\ON_{\le x}$ the class of all ordinals smaller or equal to $x$. I will write $\Suc(x)$ and $\Lim(x)$ if $x$ is a successor or limit ordinal respectively; in the former case I'll let $x_0$ be the ordinal $x$ is a successor to.

For a fixed $\alpha\in \ON$ ordinal addition $+_\alpha(\beta) = \alpha + \beta$ is defined for every $\beta\in\ON$ by the three rules

$\alpha + 0 = \alpha$.
$\alpha + \beta = (\alpha + \beta_0) + 1$ if $\Suc(\beta)$.
$\alpha + \beta = \bigcup_{\x<\b}(\a+\x)$

Say that we have shown:

Each ordinal is either $\emptyset$, a successor ordinals, or a limit ordinal.
The result of $\alpha + \beta$ for each of the three cases of $\beta$ is an ordinal.

It seems to me that we'll have already shown $+_\alpha(\beta)$ is well-defined for every $\beta$, so why do we need recursion to define $+_{\alpha}$?

Edit: I apologize for not having written before an explicit argument as to why $\a+\b$ is defined for all $\b$. Here is what I had in mind:
Lemma 1: let $\a$ be an ordinal, then so is $\a + 1 := \a\cup\{\a\}$.
Lemma 2: let $X$ be a set of ordinals, then $\bigcup X$ is an ordinal.
Lemma 3 (Transfinite Induction): for any formula $\f(x)$, we have that
\begin{split}
\ZF & \vdash \f(0) \\
 & \land
\forall\a(\f(\a)\implies \f(\a+1)) \\
 & \land \forall\a(\Lim(\a)\land\forall\b\in\a\ \f(\b)\implies\f(\a)) \\
 & \implies \forall\a \f(\a).
\end{split}
Result(?): for any fixed ordinal $\a$, ordinal addition $\a+\b$ is well-defined for any $\beta$.
Proof: we show the conditions for Lemma 3 are met, with $\f(\beta) :=$ "$\a + \b$ is well-defined".

$\a + 0$ is well-defined: trivial.

If $\a+\b$ is well-defined, then so is $\a + (\b + 1)$: as $\beta + 1$ is a successor ordinal, we have that, by definition:
$$\a + (\b + 1) := (\a + \b) + 1$$
which well-defined as so is $\a+\b$ by hypothesis and so are the successors of every ordinal by Lemma 1.

If $\Lim(\b)$ and $\forall \x<\b$ we have that $\a+\x$ is well-defined, then so is $\a+\b$: by definition


$$\a+\b = \bigcup_{\x<\b}(\a+\x)$$
which is defined as so is each $\a+\x$ by hypothesis and the union of  set of ordinals is an ordinal by Lemma 2.

Edit 2: as two answers below comment on the meaning of "well-defined", I will try to explain what I meant by it (again, sorry for not being specific before).
Using the notation explained at the beginning of the post, I think we may construct a formula $\f(x)$ with one free variable $x$ stating
\begin{split}
& x \in \ON\\
\land\ & \exists ! \text{ function $+_\a:\ON_{\le x}\to\ON$}\\
& \x = \emptyset\implies +_\a(\x) = \a\\
\land\ & \Suc(\x) \implies +_\a(\x) = +_\a(\x_0) + 1\\
\land\ & \Lim(\x) \implies +_\a(\x) = \bigcup_{\y<\x}+_\a(\y)
\end{split}
Would this formula not be allowed in the language?

See this post

@MauroALLEGRANZA I have seen it defined using Transfinite Recursion, even asked a couple of things about it before. I think I understand how the existence of $+_\alpha$ follows from Transfinite Recursion, but it seems to me it should also follow without it.

But what is your proposed definition of ordinal arithmetic without transfinite recursion?

“Definitions” 2 and 3 are circular, so not definitions at all. The transfinite recursion theorem is what tells you that there is in fact a unique operation satisfying 1-3, hence that they collectively amount to a proper definition. You are talking about “the result” before it is defined what that is.

For the same reason that we need Induction to define sum in "ordinary" arithmetic. Mathematical Induction covers all natural numbers: but in order to go up "to infinity and beyond" we need something more.

I guess by $\varphi(\beta):= $ "$\alpha+\beta$ is well-defined" you mean "the function $+_\alpha$ is defined at point $\beta$", i.e. it has $\beta$ is its domain?
What function?
How could I tell you if $\beta$ is in the domain of $+_\alpha$ if there isn't a definition of $+_\alpha$? How could that be a well-specified property? In order to answer that question, you have to define the function. Transfinite recursion is how you define the function.
There's nothing wrong with the intuition that we are defining $+_\alpha$ "gradually by induction", but a priori, that's not how definitions work, and we need to prove, rigously in set theory, that it makes sense. That's what the transfinite recursion theorem is.
And indeed we can lean on this intuition heavily in the proof. We build up an $f:Ord\to Ord$ satisfying rules 1-3 by showing, by induction, that for any ordinal $\beta$, there is a unique function $f_\beta:\beta+1\to Ord$, satisfying 1-3. This is somewhat analogous to an argument that $f$ is "defined" at every $\beta,$ with $f_\beta(\beta)$ serving as the value. The crucial idea used in the course of the induction proof that makes everything work is that if they exist, these functions must be "coherent", i.e. for $\beta < \gamma,$ $f_\beta= f_\gamma\upharpoonright (\beta+1),$ since $f_\gamma\upharpoonright (\beta+1)$ is a function $\beta+1\to Ord$ satisfying 1-3, and $f_\beta$ is the unique function fitting this description. So this is kind of like saying each "partial definition" "builds on top of the previous ones". This coherence condition then allows us to assemble $f:=\bigcup_\beta f_\beta$ at the end.

I edited the post after you posted your answer. Is what you describe in your third paragraoh analogous to the definition I gave?

@Sam Yes, pretty much. Prove that formula holds for all ordinals $x$ by transfinite induction, then define $+_\alpha(x)$ to be the value of that unique function at $x.$ This is a proof of the transfinite recursion theorem, only for the specific conditions 1-3 for ordinal addition rather than generic recursion conditions. But the proof for a generic 1-3 is no different.

@Sam (By "that unique function" I mean the one that $\varphi(x)$ asserts exists. Also,  it must also be proved that the $(+)\alpha(x)$ defined on all of ON at the end satisfies 1-3, which is easy. May be slightly better notationally-speaking to use a different notation than $(+)\alpha$ for the variable denoting the unique function in $\varphi(x)$ to avoid confusion with the one defined at the end (as I did with $f_\beta$ vs $f$), but of course this winds up just being the restriction of it to an initial segment.)


Say that we have shown:



The result of $\alpha + \beta$ for each of the three cases of $\beta$ is an ordinal.



It seems to me that we'll have already shown $+_\alpha(\beta)$ is well-defined for every $\beta$, so why do we need recursion to define $+_{\alpha}$?

Definition rules 2 and 3 are recursive, so they ensure that the result of $\alpha + \beta$ for each of the three cases of $\beta$ exists provided there exist the results of $\alpha+\xi$ for $\xi<\beta$, thus we need to use Transfinite Induction to conclude that the result of $\alpha + \beta$ exists for any ordinal $\beta$.

we show the conditions for Lemma 3 are met, with $\varphi(\beta) :=$ "$\alpha + \beta$ is well-defined".

As far as I understand, "$\alpha + \beta$ is well-defined" is not a formula admissible in ZFC.

We do not attempt to show that ordinal addition is well-defined for every ordinal number. We show, so to speak, ordinal addition, the operation itself, is fundamentally a mathematical induction.
(1) and (2) in the question are both the clauses of the standard inductive definition. (3) extends the induction with the least upper bound of all previous values that have been obtained when the induction reaches a limit ordinal.
